# Nagios Core 3.5 change Date format

Tags: configuration, date, nagios

How can the Date/Time format that Nagios uses everywhere be changed to
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

[image: actual Nagios format]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A date/time format of "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" is configurable in the [main configuration file](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html) with the `date_format` option set to `iso8601`:

> This option allows you to specify what kind of date/time format Nagios should use in the web interface and date/time macros. Possible options (along with example output) include:

> | Option | Output Format | Sample Output |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | us | MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS | 06/30/2002 03:15:00 |
> | euro | DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS | 30/06/2002 03:15:00 |
> | iso8601 | YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS | 2002-06-30 03:15:00 |
> | strict-iso8601 | YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS | 2002-06-30T03:15:00 |

You will need to restart Nagios for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it was easy, if you know where to look.

In the configuration file:
/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

It was self documented on the configuration file:

```
# DATE FORMAT OPTION
# This option determines how short dates are displayed. Valid options
# include:
#   us      (MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS)
#   euro        (DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS)
#   iso8601     (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
#   strict-iso8601  (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
#

date_format=us
```

Jeff Schaller: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Happy to help! There's no need to add an additional Answer if it just says the same thing as another one. The fact that it's upvoted or has a checkmark is an indication to the SE system that this question is Answered. Thanks!